# Symfony 2.8 Entity when access displayAction Route SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "t10"

Tags: orm, entity, symfony-2.8

hi im trying added customer section when customer can do something like see address list and add/update/delete address. a

so im trying my first step make customer entity like this

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Customer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="customer")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CustomerRepository")
 */
class Customer 
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="text")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="text")
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="customer")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Cart", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
    */
    protected $cart;

    // public function __construct()
    // {
    //     parent::__construct();
    //     // your own logic
    // }

    // other properties and methods


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set address
     *
     * @param string $address
     *
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function setAddress($address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get address
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * Set cart
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Cart $cart
     * @return User
     */
    public function setCart(\AppBundle\Entity\Cart $cart = null)
    {
        $this->cart = $cart;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get cart
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Cart 
     */
    public function getCart()
    {
        return $this->cart;
    }

    // public function __construct()
    // {
    //     parent::__construct();

    //     $this->addRole("ROLE_CUSTOMER");
    // }
}
```

and when i access localhost/customer i got error message like this

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name
>   AS name_2, t0.address AS address_3, t0.user_id AS user_id_4, t5.id AS
>   id_6, t5.total_price AS total_price_7, t5.quantity AS quantity_8,
>   t5.user_id AS user_id_9 FROM customer t0 LEFT JOIN cart t5 ON
>   t5.user_id = t10.id':
>
> SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry
>   for table "t10" LINE 1: ..._9 FROM customer t0 LEFT JOIN cart t5 ON
>   t5.user_id = t10.id ^

ive done open some thread in stackoverflow but many of them still confusing me to get the clear answer how to fix this issue,the topic mostly discuss about postgres not the entity.

and this is my customer controller

```
 <?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Entity\Customer;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("customer/new", name="new_address")
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new Customer();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('address', TextType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit'))
        ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $user = $form->getData();
            $doct = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $doct->persist($user);

            $doct->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('address_list');
        } else {
            return $this->render('customer/new.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/customer", name="address_list")
     */
    public function displayAction()
    {
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Customer')
            ->findAll();

            return $this->render('customer/display.html.twig', array('data' => $user));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/customer/update/{id}", name="address_update")
     */
    public function updateAction($id, Request $request)
    {
        $doct = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $doct->getRepository('AppBundle:Customer')->find($id);

        if (!$user) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'No customer found for id '.$id
            );
        }
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('address', TextType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit'))
        ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $user = $form->getData();
                $doct = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                $doct->persist($user);

                $doct->flush();

                return $this->redirectToRoute('address_display');
            }
        return $this->render('customer/new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("customer/delete/{id}", name="customer_delete")
     */
    public function deleteAction($id) {
        $doct = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $doct->getRepository('AppBundle:Customer')->find($id);

        if (!$user) {
            throw $this->createNotfoundException('No customer found for id ',$id);
        }
        $doct->remove($user);
        $doct->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('address_display');
    }
}
```

i expect the output i can access the customer display action router again and show the list all data from customer controller.

Answer (score 0):

i dunno why this can solve this issue,so i try to uncomment this line

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->addRole("ROLE_CUSTOMER");
    }
```

its solved the issue i can open and access the localhost/customer